# I cannot get the correct TD to display with angular

Tags: c#, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to get the td to display based on true/false values for Loan. Everything is solid until I hit this point, where it prints out both of the td's instead td corresponding to the value of true/false

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="dvd in dvds | filter: dvdFilter">
        <td>{{dvd.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{dvd.Rating.RatingName}}</td>
        <td>{{dvd.MovieDirector}}</td>
        <td><a href={{dvd.Website}} class="btn btn-primary">IMDb</a></td>
        <td>
            <button value={{dvd.DvdId}} class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDelete" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
        </td>
        <td ui-if{{dvd.Loan}}="true" style="color: green;">Available</td>
        <td ui-if{{dvd.Loan}}="false" style="color: red;">Out on Loan</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: use ng-if for that

Comment: syntax ui-if{{dvd.Loan}}= does not look right

Comment: ng-if gives me the same result @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer ends up being

```
    <td ng-if"dvd.Loan == true" style="color: red;">Out on Loan</td>
    <td ng-if"dvd.Loan == false" style="color: green;">Available</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax is just a bit off. Try this on your `td` lines:

```
<td ng-if="dvd.Loan == 'true'" style="color: green;">Available</td>
<td ng-if="dvd.Loan == 'false'" style="color: red;">Out on Loan</td>
```

Comment: The code does not like that. It returns a parse error.

Comment: Still no, it is a syntax parse in the angular file that it given to me by vis studio

Comment: I'm not seeing a syntax error in my answer. Are you sure there is a `Loan` on the `dvd`?

Comment: Yes. the answer ended up being "dvd.Loan == true/false" w/o single quotes around true/false. thanks! @ethorn10